# creating rpm of java project with apache-maven

Tags: java, maven, version, rpm, rpm-maven-plugin

I am new to maven and using apache-maven-3.0.5. I have a git repository named Project1, and there are many other sub-projects inside Project1. I want to change the location of the version file (which is created after installing rpm of Project1) in file Project1/rpm/pom.xml.

To see the effect of the change, I want to create rpm and install in order to verify that the version file is created at modified location.

Can someone please tell the steps to create rpm and where it will be placed ? Please note that the project has proper pom.xml and can be built successfully with mvn clean install command.

The problem is I dont know how to create rpm all over again (that will include also the subprojects inside Project1) and wehre it is stored. I would really appreciate any help regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the rpm-maven-plugin creates the rpm as part of the packaging phase of the maven lifecycle. By default this places the rpm under the target directory in an rpm sub directory. If you use the install goal it will place the rpm (using maven naming conventions) into your local maven repository.

If you have a multi-module build, then your best bet is likely to run `mvn clean install` from the top level project to cause all child projects to build and install in the pre-defined order.